# How do you make Salesforce ping my application?

Tags: database, synchronization, salesforce

I have data in Salesforce and run another application that works with the same data.  The current workflow is that when data is entered into the custom application, it sends the information to Salesforce via SOAP.  I want to establish the reverse link; when a value is changed on the Salesforce side, I want Salesforce to ping my application with the changes.  Does Salesforce have a feature to do this?  Something equivalent to a trigger maybe?

My current solution is mindless iteration through all Salesforce records.  This is slow, hits the API limit often, and keeps data stale too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **You can do this using Streaming API**

> Introduction:
>
> 1. Use Streaming API to receive notifications for changes to Salesforce data.
> 2. Use to push relevant data in realtime, instead of having to refresh the screen to get new information.  Protocols Use for Connection:
> 3. The Bayeux protocol and CometD both use long polling.
> 4. Bayeux is a protocol for transporting asynchronous messages, primarily over HTTP.
> 5. CometD is a scalable HTTP-based event routing bus that uses an AJAX push technology pattern known as Comet. It implements the Bayeux
>      protocol. The Salesforce servers use version 2.0 of CometD.
>
> How it Works:
>
> 1. Create a PushTopic based on a SOQL query. This defines the channel. (PushTopic is a standard object).
> 2. Clients subscribe to the channel.
> 3. A record is created, updated, deleted, or undeleted (an event occurs). The changes to that record are evaluated.
> 4. If the record changes match the criteria of the PushTopic query, a notification is generated by the server and received by the subscribed
>      clients.

Please check this link : http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api_streaming/

Comment: Interesting information.  How does one deal with the unreliable nature of the of Streaming API?  From the docs: "Streaming API doesn’t guarantee durability and reliable delivery of notifications. Streaming servers don’t maintain any client state and don’t keep track of what’s delivered. The client may not receive messages for a variety of reasons..."  If there's a problem where my application fails to receive an update, how would I detect this?

Comment: I think Message delivary status is not possible to catch. please check this link: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bDsmAAE

Comment: @hekevintran This is new Streaming API updates on message durability (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_streaming_api_durability.htm). Please check it may be it's useful to you.